# JAVA ERROR .need suggestion in form of comments or codes if possible pls,

Tags: java

as i am newbie.i have tried some code..pls suggeesst some problem.. am getting this error.pls help me solve this problem..

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
package calculator;

public class calc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

            private int valueA;
            private int valueB;
            private String operator;
            private char operatorA;

            public int getvalueA() {
            return valueA;
            }

            public int getvalueB() {
            return valueB;
            }

            {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter problem.");

            {

            valueA = keyboard.nextInt();
            valueB = keyboard.nextInt();
            operator = keyboard.next();
            operatorA = operator.charAt(0);

            int add = valueA + valueB;
            int minus = valueA - valueB;
            int multiply = valueA * valueB;
            int divide = valueA / valueB;
            String clearScreen = null;


            switch (operatorA) {
            case '+':
            System.out.println(add);
            break;

            case '-':
            System.out.println(minus);
            break;

            case '*':
            System.out.println(multiply);
            break;

            case '/':
            System.out.println(divide);

            case 'C':
            System.out.println(clearScreen);
            break;

            default:
            System.out.println("unknown operator '" + operator + "'. Please try again.");
            break;
            }

            }
        }
```

pls provide corrective points???

:   Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args) { }` is how your method begins...

Comment: @kon i have told,i am newbie.no way to compare your knowledge with a newbie like me....

Comment: No need to get down on yourself :). I was just pointing out the problem I found. I recommend using an integrated development environment (IDE) in the future. Something like Eclipse would help you avoid this problem (or at least catch it immediately as it is created). Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

The main issue the compiler was complaining about was the incorrect placement of braces (one was missing at the end). However, you probably didn't write the code in the right place either. You probably wanted to have most of it in `main()`, but instead you had it in the constructor and so it won't run without at least instantiating an object of type `Calc`. Really, you want to refactor your code to something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calc {
    private static int valueA;
    private static int valueB;
    private static String operator;
    private static char operatorA;

    public int getValueA() {
        return valueA;
    }

    public int getValueB() {
        return valueB;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter problem.");

        valueA = keyboard.nextInt();
        valueB = keyboard.nextInt();
        operator = keyboard.next();
        operatorA = operator.charAt(0);

        int add = valueA + valueB;
        int minus = valueA - valueB;
        int multiply = valueA * valueB;
        int divide = valueA / valueB;
        String clearScreen = null;

        switch (operatorA) {
        case '+':
            System.out.println(add);
            break;

        case '-':
            System.out.println(minus);
            break;

        case '*':
            System.out.println(multiply);
            break;

        case '/':
            System.out.println(divide);

        case 'C':
            System.out.println(clearScreen);
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("unknown operator '" + operator
                    + "'. Please try again.");
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

That is, if you want to access the variables in the class from main, they will have to be declared as static (as main is/has to be static) as I have done for you here.

Alternatively, you could instantiate an object of type `Calc` and access its members via the getters you've created and then the variables do not have to be static (as you perhaps originally intended). This is generally cleaner and I'll leave that to you as an exercise. Note the standard naming conventions in Java: **camelCase** and **class names start with a capital letter**.

Comment: And to name things properly and know about the proper use of the `static` keyword.

Comment: I would also remove the extraneous braces after System.out.println("Enter problem.").

Comment: Good catch! Removed them.

Comment: Just a small note that the brackets in the original code are  [initialization blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) not the constructor. Since they are not static blocks the code would not have run without an instance of the class anyways. Good answer btw

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your braces match up with methods. Your code to run it also needs to be a method.

```
    public static void parse{
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter problem.");
             valueA = keyboard.nextInt();
             valueB = keyboard.nextInt();
```

> ```
>           operator = keyboard.next();
>           operatorA = operator.charAt(0);
>
>           int add = valueA + valueB;
>           int minus = valueA - valueB;
>           int multiply = valueA * valueB;
>           int divide = valueA / valueB;
>           String clearScreen = null;
>
>
>           switch (operatorA) {
>           case '+':
>           System.out.println(add);
>           break;
>
>           case '-':
>           System.out.println(minus);
>           break;
>
>           case '*':
>           System.out.println(multiply);
>           break;
>
>           case '/':
>           System.out.println(divide);
>
>           case 'C':
>           System.out.println(clearScreen);
>           break;
>
>            default:
>            System.out.println("unknown operator '" + operator + "'. Please try     again.");
>           break;
>            }
> ```

then call the method from your your main method.

Answer (score 0):

You have some weird curly brackets placement.

Here what should be ok:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
package calculator;

public class calc {

    private int valueA;
    private int valueB;
    private String operator;

    private char operatorA;

    public int getvalueA() {
       return valueA;
    }

    public int getvalueB() {
       return valueB;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter problem.");

            valueA = keyboard.nextInt();
            valueB = keyboard.nextInt();
            operator = keyboard.next();
            operatorA = operator.charAt(0);

            int add = valueA + valueB;
            int minus = valueA - valueB;
            int multiply = valueA * valueB;
            int divide = valueA / valueB;
            String clearScreen = null;


            switch (operatorA) {
               case '+':
               System.out.println(add);
               break;

               case '-':
               System.out.println(minus);
               break;

               case '*':
               System.out.println(multiply);
               break;

               case '/':
               System.out.println(divide);

               case 'C':
               System.out.println(clearScreen);
               break;

               default:
               System.out.println("unknown operator '" + operator + "'. Please try again.");
               break;    
            }
     }
  }
```